# Property 'sharedFileUtils' not found on object of type 'CCFileUtils'

Tags: ios6, cocos2d-iphone, cocos3d

I'm just getting started running Cocos3d and right out of the box trying to run the demo file I'm getting a compile error. Here's the error in the log:

```
/Users/user/Developer/Tutorials/Cocos3dInitialTest/Cocos3dInitialTest/cocos3d/cocos3d/Nodes/CC3BitmapLabelNode.m:140:36: error: property 'sharedFileUtils' not found on object of type 'CCFileUtils'
    NSString *fullpath = [CCFileUtils.sharedFileUtils fullPathFromRelativePath: fontFile];
```

I'm sure it's a simple fix but, ah, so much initial code to get through. Don't want to overheat my brain right of the bat if possible.

Answer (score 0):

sharedFileUtils is a method, not a property.

Try this way:

```
[CCFileUtils sharedFileUtils]
```

Your code should look like this:

```
NSString *fullpath = [[CCFileUtils sharedFileUtils] fullPathFromRelativePath: fontFile];
```